# can i register using same email id for a 3 different profile types

Tags: users

This project is related to add social service work details into my website. 
I used profile2 module to create a 3 profile types and its create successfully.
we have 3 profile types,
1) Single User
2) Comapny
3) NGO

Can i register on above 3 profile types using same email Id because if single user is chairman of company and they wants to register as comany using same email id so it is possible.
same like if single user is chairman of NGO and also they wants to register NGO using same email Id then it is possible or not.

How i can manage this situation.please help me

Comment: Profile2 module allows user to have multiple profiles. User does not have to create separate account for profile types, it is one user to many profile mapping out of the box. Does that answer your question?

Comment: actually we have to use same email id for 3 profile types because of above reason

Answer (score 0):

You may need [Shared Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharedemail) module for this. It allows multiple email accounts with same email address.

Comment: I checked shared email module but in configuration there is no setting found

Comment: May be no settings required for this module.

Comment: i created 3 profile types using profile2 module. so it is interconnected with profile2 module.

Comment: It simply allows the drupal registration account with same email id again.

Comment: yup, not works for me.

Comment: Any suggestion..can it be done in drupal or should i do this in normal php website

Comment: You should not need to use the same email id again and again. Checkout what arpitr says in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

A lot more depends on the scope of functionality and how will it grow, which can not be answered here I believe.

Profile 2 module separates user account from user profile i.e. account properties i.e. email password will be shared across all profile types.

Now different profile type create/edit/view permission can be handled by setting up user roles. So with your example it will go like
User with chairman role(assuming we have chairman as drupal user role) can create/update/ profiles as company/single user/ngo.

Again there will not be separate registration process for building profiles.